# Why it shows cu(10): error: expected a ")" in c file

Tags: cuda

The problem looks easy to solve but I find all time and didn't find where need I to add a )

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define N 512

__global__ void add(int *a, int *b, int *c){
    //*c = *a + *b;
    c[blockIdx.x] = a[blockIdx.x] + b[blockIdx.x];
}


void random_ints(int* temp, int N){
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < N; i++ ){
        temp[i] = rand();
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    int *a, *b, *c;
    int *d_a, *d_b, *d_c;
    int size = N * sizeof(int);

    //allocate space for device copies of a,b,c
    cudaMalloc((void **)&d_a, size);
    cudaMalloc((void **)&d_b, size);
    cudaMalloc((void **)&d_c, size);

    //setup input values
    a = (int *)malloc(size);random_ints(a, N);
    b = (int *)malloc(size);random_ints(b, N);
    c = (int *)malloc(size);

    //copy imputs to devices
    cudaMemcpy(d_a, a, size, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    cudaMemcpy(d_b, b, size, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

    //launch add kernel on GPU
    add<<<N,1>>>(d_a, d_b, d_c);

    //copy result back to host
    cudaMemcpy(c, d_c, size, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
    printf("c:%d\n",c);
    //clean up
    free(a); free(b); free(c);
    cudaFree(d_a); 
    cudaFree(d_b);
    cudaFree(d_c);
    return 0;
}
```

The main purpose of file but I think it doen't matter

I want to allocate space in GPU to calculate array, just add element of array A and element of array B to array C

Comment: Hi, If you ever have an syntax issue like this one and you cant find it. Start with removing lines until you have a minimal example that reproduces the issue. I suspect that had you done this you would have found the problem yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The preprocessor will replace the `N` macro:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define N 512

void random_ints(int* temp, int N){
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < N; i++ ){
        temp[i] = rand();
    }
}
```

Will be replaced by:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void random_ints(int* temp, int 512){
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 512; i++ ){
        temp[i] = rand();
    }
}
```

The prototype of you function became wrong.

You can just write:

```
void random_ints(int* temp, int size){
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++ ){
        temp[i] = rand();
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't understand. You voted to close the question, and yet you answered it?